# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: WITH

Tags: java, sql-server, hsqldb

Im getting this exception when trying to execute a SELECT... WITH (NOLOCK).

Does anyone know how to handle/overcome this?

props:

```
database.jdbc.datasource.class=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource
database.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:database;sql.syntax_mss=true;sql.regular_names=false
```

stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: WITH
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 52 more
```

Comment: Are you trying to use SQL-Server syntax on HSQLDB? Add the query you are using.

Comment: Yes, i'm using it for unit tests.  It's a jdbi query:  SELECT * FROM X WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IdX = :idX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not yet supported but will be supported in future versions. For the current version of HSQLDB, you need to remove the `WITH(NOLOCK)` from the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks fredt , do you know if there is a open issue related to this so i can follow up?

Comment: This type of syntax compatibility is normally added when requested. You can go to the HSQLDB web site (http://hsqldb.org) and suggest any such feature.